# ¿Como obtener todas las posiciones de un mismo carácter en una String?

Tags: php

Mi problema es que requiero poder obtener la ubicación de un mismo carácter en una cadena, es decir, localizar la posición de varios caracteres que son iguales a un mismo carácter. **Ejemplo:**

```
$string='Hola como estas, Hola estas bien y Hola porque no respondes';
```

De este String quiero obtener todas las posiciones de Hola.

Investigando encontré un método:

```
strpos()
```

Pero este solo permite obtener la posición de la primera instancia del **carácter** o **sub-cadena** de búsqueda, es decir, solo me permitiría buscar Hola solo una vez y no tres veces.

Encontré otro método:

```
substr_count()
```

Este me permite obtener la cantidad de veces que se repite el **carácter** o **sub-cadena** en una cadena, es decir, el numero o cantidad de Hola en este caso serian **3**.

Sin importar ello no pienso una forma de como usar ambos métodos para obtener mi objetivo, **o simplemente usar uno que haga lo de ambos**.

Gracias y espero su respuesta.

Comment: ¿De un mismo carácter  o de una palabra? No es lo mismo.

Comment: de acuerdo un carácter es una unidad que puede complementar una palabra, pero a lo que me refiero es a identificar ese caracter o un conjunto de caracter, ya que un string cuenta las posiciones **Hola como estas** este no comienza a contar desde la H si no desde Hola como si este fuese un solo carácter a menos que yo indique solo la busque de **H** eso es lo que entiendo de la devolución ``strpos()`` de este método

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Puedes implementar la función [`strpos_recursive` compartida en las notas de contribución del Manual de PHP](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.strpos.php#107678).

Sería esto:

```
<?php
    function strpos_recursive($haystack, $needle, $offset = 0, &$results = array()) {                
        $offset = strpos($haystack, $needle, $offset);
        if($offset === false) {
            return $results;            
        } else {
            $results[] = $offset;
            return strpos_recursive($haystack, $needle, ($offset + 1), $results);
        }
    }
?>
```

Y para usarla:

```
$string='Hola como estas, Hola estas bien y Hola porque no respondes';
$out=strpos_recursive($string,"Hola");
print_r($out);
```

**Salida:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => 0
    [1] => 17
    [2] => 35
)
```

Como ves, la función devuelve un array con las posiciones donde se encontró la palabra (sirve también para un carácter, claro está).

Ahí tendrías las dos informaciones que buscas. Haciendo un `count($out);`  sabrías cuántas veces el dato se repite. Y leyendo el array sabrías las posiciones de cada ocurrencia del dato.

Answer (score 4):

Puedes usar la función [str_word_count()](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.str-word-count.php), la cual entre otras cosas,

> devuelve un array asociativo, donde la clave es la posición numérica de una palabra dentro del string y el valor es la palabra en sí.

Combinando esto con la función [key](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.key.php), podemos obtener el valor de la posición para la palabra deseada.

Un ejemplo sencillo de esta implementación sería:

```
<?php
    $str = 'Hola como estas, Hola estas bien y Hola porque no respondes';
    $arr = str_word_count($str, 2);
    while ($word = current($arr)) {
        if ($word == 'Hola') {
            echo key($arr).'</br>';
        }
        next($arr);
    }
?>
```

Como se puede apreciar, recorremos el array elemento por elemento usando la función [current()](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.current.php). Por cada elemento del array, comparamos el valor del elemento con la palabra buscada, si hay coincidencia se imprime el valor del `key` de dicha coincidencia, que corresponde a la posición en la que aparece nuestra palabra en el `string` original.

Espero que sea lo que estabas buscando.

Answer (score 2):

Yo te recomendaría en todo caso usar "explode" separas toda la cadena en la palabra que buscas, y luego la unes, para saber las posiciones, solo cuentas el leng de lo que separaste, la otra idea es usar un metodo mas sencillo y ese seria recorrer toda la cadena en busca de la palabra "Hola" con un substring, y vas comparando la posición actual.

Ejemplo:

```
    $string='Hola como estas, Hola estas bien y Hola porque no respondes';

$longitud=strlen($string);

for ($i = 0; $i <= $longitud; $i++) {

    $subCadena=substr($string, $i, 4);

    if ($subCadena=="Hola"){
        echo $i;
        echo "<br>";
    }  
}
```

Comment: Sería genial para mejorar tu aporte que muestres en código como hacer lo que mencionas

Comment: tienes razón, deja lo subo. unos ejemplos